# Using otf file as font for website

Tags: php, fonts, opentype

I"m trying to use an otf file as my font for my website, but for some reason it's not changing the font to it at all. I downloaded the zip for the otf file, but the only file I uploaded to my directory is the FontAwesome.otf file. What am I doing wrong?

```
@font-face { 
font-family: 'FontAwesome'; 
src: url('FontAwesome.otf') format('opentype'); 
} 
body { 
font-size: 36px; 
} 
#div1 { 
font-family: 'FontAwesome'; 
border: 1px solid red; 
} 

<div id = 'div1'> The quick </div> The quick
```

Comment: Recommendation: this is fontawesome, use the WOFF version instead, so that every browser will work, instead of "just some". Even better, don't use your own copy, [use their CDN](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What do we add to the font-face in css after we add this line to the <head> of our document? <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Unless adding the single line to <head> will make everything in the document to be font awesome? In that case, can we set it to font-face, so we can pick where we want the font to be font awesome?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It literally just says add this line to the <head> and then the explanation stops right there. No explanation on what to do next.

Comment: that's because that's where it ends? You add the fontawesome `<link>` to the head. Then in your content you can use fontawesome classes, just like you would otherwise. The CDN stylesheet loads both the fontawesome resources and sets up all the classes fontawesome lets you use.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What? That makes no sense at all. Normally, you set the name of the font-family in font-face, and provide the src there too, and then you use the name of the font-family as you normally would in css. Classes? Resources? I don't care about any of that. I just want to use the font itself.

Comment: it's an icon font, you'd use it for icons, which are non-semantic and as such should not be real text. Unless you don't care about accessibility at all, in which case "...what?". Yes: if you just want "a webfont", then add the link, done, you can now use `font-family: Fontawesome` wherever you need it in your own CSS, because their stylesheet [has the @font-face load instructions in it](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css). Why you'd do this for FontAwesome, rather than normal font, I have no idea. FontAwesome is not for typesetting plain text.

Comment: Minimal example: http://jsbin.com/gabiwesiyo/edit?html,output - works fine (also, a really bad way to use FontAwesome).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The square with the question marks inside them. How did you make them?

Comment: Those are letters (well, they're unicode entries, not strictly speaking "letters"). None of the fonts in the font stack for the content on the left support them so you see the ".notdef" glyph from whatever is the last font the browser tries to use. And then in the actual preview of the code, which uses the FontAwesome font, which *does* have glyphs for those entries, you see normal shapes. It's why FontAwesome makes no sense as text font: it only has icon implementations, so using it for anyting other than (unicode) icons won't work, and makes pretty much zero sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have to specify full path or relative path from php script to font file in src: url
2) your browser has to support otf fonts